# Adding a page break to a book via Scheme

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

I am writing a Scheme function to semi-automatically compile a few different books from a source file (with various sets of scores, instruments etc. included in each book).
When handling a Book object, I can append a score to it quite simply:

```
(ly:book-add-score! book score)
```

However, I would also want to insert some page breaks between those scores. The obvious solution does not work:

```
(ly:book-add-score! book #{ \score { \pageBreak } #})
```

produces the output "warning: skipping zero-duration score", and of course no page break. I guess that I must append the page break, not as a score, but as markup (using a variant of the `add-text` function from `scm/lily-library.scm` maybe)? However, every attempt to do this resulted in an (opaque) Guile error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toplevel `\pageBreak` et al. calls are translated to special objects that are called "page markers". This is internally done using `collect-music-aux`, which takes as first argument the score handler (in your case this would be something like `(lambda (score) (ly:book-add-score! book score))`) and the music as second argument.

So you’d do something like

```
(collect-music-aux
 (lambda (score) (ly:book-add-score! book score))
 #{ \pageBreak #})
```

Of course you could also directly create the page marker you need and pass that to `ly:book-add-score!`.

Remark: This function handles toplevel music expressions, so if you do `{ c d e }` this function is responsible for invoking `scorify-music` to wrap this into a score object.